# Meaning of word "hire"

Tags: meaning

What does *hire* mean in the line of [Swinburne's "A Cameo"](http://www.poemhunter.com/best-poems/algernon-charles-swinburne/a-cameo/):

> Pleasure with gaunt hands that grasped their hire.

Comment: You did not include enough context.  (In fact, the entire poem is probably not enough.)  Bear in mind that "hire" is a very old word that has had many meanings over the centuries, plus this poet is intentionally writing in archaic metaphors.

Comment: What @HotLicks said. In addition, *hire* has different meanings/uses for BrE and AmE.

Answer (score 3):

On a quick search, I did not find much scholarly attention to or analysis of Swinburne's *Cameo* or treatment of his use of *hire*.

However, I did come across this college or high school essay, *[Prosody and the Release from Cares: A New Critical Approach to Swinburne’s “A Cameo”](https://www.scribd.com/mobile/document/33760612/Prosody-and-the-Release-from-Cares-A-New-Critical-Approach-to-Swinburne-s-A-Cameo)* by Edward Olan Lockhart, which states:

> Pleasure held his "hire," Satiety, in an unfailing grip. Hire could at the time Swinburne wrote this poem have been used in its modern sense, an employee, yet this made little sense. Pleasure paid nothing to Satiety. However, in light of Anthony Harrison's scholarship which showed Swinburne's  great familiarity and love of medieval literature (1-9), a more archaic definition of "hire" seemed far more appropriate. **Hire in this instance meant reward, especially a captured one** (OED). Pleasure, in part, kept Satiety from his satisfaction.

Here is the OED's full [entry for *hire* in the sense of "reward"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/87207?rskey=6opGpj&result=1#eid):

> 3. *fig*. Reward, recompense, payment (for work or service of any kind).
>      ?c1225  (▸?a1200)    *Ancrene Riwle* (Cleo. C.vi) (1972) 314   Hare hure schal beon þe eche blisse of heoue [?a1289 Scribe D heouene].
>      a1300   *Cursor Mundi* 23192   Sathanas..sal casten be..in a stincand stang o fire; þar sal be yolden him his hire.
>      1382   *Bible* (Wycliffite, E.V.) Rom. vi. 22   Treuli the hyris of synne, deeth.
>      1481   Caxton tr. *Hist. Reynard Fox* (1970) 29   Our lorde god shal ones rewarde them their hyre.
>      c1560   A. Scott *Poems* (S.T.S.) xxxii. 10   Schort plesour, lang displesour; Repentence is the hyre.
>      1608   D. Tuvill *Ess. Politicke, & Morall* f. 2v,   Some..that thinke the very disturbance of things established, a sufficient hyre to set them on worke.
>      1841   G. P. R. James *Brigand* iv,   And make her hand the hire of this Savoyard.

I include it here because I find an incongruity between the sense of "reward" (for services rendered) and Lockhart's emphasis on "especially a captured one".

I don't see any evidence of that connotation in the OED entry or any of its historical attestations, though of course *reward* and *prize* are closely related, and *prize* does have [an explicit sense](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/151648?rskey=Kk4gh2&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) where it means:

> Something seized or captured by force, esp. in war; booty or plunder; a captive of war.

To resolve this issue, we could look into the referenced analysis of *hire* by Harrison.

As Scribd only allows one to preview works, I was not able to pull up the essay's bibliography, but a quick search found a book on The Victorian Web titled *[Swinburne's Medievalism: A Study in Victorian Love Poetry](http://www.victorianweb.org/authors/swinburne/harrison/contents.html)* by Anthony H. Harrison, Professor of English, North Carolina State University, so this is likely the work being cited.

Unfortunately, that work does not appear to address *Cameo* directly or its use of *hire* specifically, so Lockhart was likely using it only to support his argument that Swinburne was employing a medieval (or simply a non-modern) sense of *hire*, not his specific interpretation of that word in the "captured prize" sense.